# Comparing Given String To An Array sub property

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

I'm building an array of `players` which will be added to when `solver` is not found within the `name` properties inside `players`

```
let players = []

let solver = 'Any Name Given'

// This if statement is the issue : How to check the name properties and compare to solver 
// If the solver's name is already in players : add +1 point
if(players.includes(solver)){

   // Give The Player +1 point

   return console.log('Player Exists')

 } else {

   // Add The newPlayer to players with a starting point 
   let newPlayer = [name = solver, points = 1]
   players.push(newPlayer)

}
```

How do I compare `solver` inside `name` of `players`. I've tried `players[name]` and `players.name` with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `else`, you should be having:

```
const newPlayer = {name: solver, points: 1};
```

i.e. an object, rather than an array. So that you have `players` array which will always have `player` objects

Now, since what you have is an array of objects, you need to use something like [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find whether an object matching your condition exists or not:

The `if` condition can be replaced by:

```
if (players.some(player => player.name === solver))
```

I just saw that you want to increase the points of the found player by `1`. In that case you should be using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `some` so that you can access the found player and update its `points` property. So do this:

```
const player = players.find(player => player.name === solver);

if (player) {
    player.points++;
} else {
    const newPlayer = {name: solver, points: 1};
    players.push(newPlayer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the only question left is how can I get the `points` property of the existing object in the `if` statement to add a point

Comment: @Elitezen Saw that part of question late, Updated the answer to show how you can increment `points` property of the found player.